# Find determinant $\det M$, where $m_{ij}=a_ia_j$, and $m_{ii}=a^2_i+k$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let ${a_1,\dots,a_n}$ --- sequence and $k\ne 0$.
Define matrix $M$ in following way: $m_{ij}=a_ia_j$ if $i\ne j$, and $m_{ii}=a^2_i+k$. Find $\det M$.

Comment: It looks like $k^n + ka_1^2 + \cdots + ka_n^2$, but I don't see how to prove it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $M=aa^T+kI$. To find $\det(M)$, you may determine $M$'s eigenvalues, or apply the [matrix determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) for rank-1 update to a matrix.